# drools guvnor repository configuration with jboss 7

Tags: java, jboss, drools, jackrabbit, guvnor

In `drools-guvnor.war/WEB-INF/components.xml` there is a `repositoryConfiguration` entry that I would like to make dynamic based on some jboss properties.

For instance, if `app.ear` is deployed under jboss-as\server\default\deploy
the configuration should be something like:

```
<component name="repositoryConfiguration">
    <property name="homeDirectory">jboss-as\server\default\data</property>
</component>
```

where `jboss-as\server\default` comes from the jboss properties.

Is this possible in any way without touching to the .ear?
(Version of jboss is eap 4.3)